# how to make or add ibm watson languages ​other than 13 default languages

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

how to make or add watson languages ​​other than 13 default languages 
(Arabic,Brazilian Portuguese,Chinese (Simplified),Chinese (Traditional),
Dutch,Czech,French,English (US),German,Italian,Japanese,Korean,Spanish)

Answer (score 1):

This technique is totally unsupported and depending how you approach gives good or really poor results.

First determine what language is closest to the unsupported language you want to use. In that there are shared nuances between the two languages. Optionally use English.

Capture your questions to build the intents, then use a language translation tool to translate from your language to the supported language. Train on that.

Then at your application layer you would translate the end users input before sending to Watson Assistant.

For the returning message, Watson Assistant already supports UTF-8, so you can put your responses in your target language.

It’s important to use the same translation engine when asking a question to the system. It may turn the question into garbage, but it may find the correct intent if similar questions mistranslated.

You will need to do the same with entities when training as well.

Comment: Alternatively if the unsupported language uses latin letters, it is possible to again use the closest language and train intents and entities on examples spelled as they would be spelled in the unsupported language. The precision might be ok. But also not officialy supported.